# How do make a zsh function in a way that I can enter a string without quotes, but it gets interpreted with quotes?

Tags: zsh

I want to make a function that would run something like this:

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best' "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM"
```

Currently, in .zshrc, I've been trying

```
downloadyoutube(){
    youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best' "$1"
```

But it still wants me to add the quotes around the URL when I call it.

Instead, I would like to run

```
downloadyoutube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
```

without quotes.

And not

```
downloadyoutube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Without `'`quotes`'`, special characters will be interpreted before it is passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Kusalananda  said, `noglob` is the way to go; you can define your function as is and then use `alias` to include `noglob`:

```
downloadyoutube(){
  youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best' "$1"
}
alias downloadyoutube="noglob downloadyoutube"
```

Anyways, what you're trying to do with these arguments is moot: `youtube-dl` defaults to it for years now; read the current `man` page!

---

I'd like to stress that Kusalananda is right:

1. you even need `'`, not only `"`, here, lest you want a few special characters to become problems,
2. even turning off globbing doesn't help against event/ redirect characters; since every Youtube URL will contain `&`, you better just configure your shell to automatically replace pasted `&` within a string (not at end of line) by `\&`; my zsh does that automagically, and I think I've got oh-my-zsh to blame for that.

Comment: Note that the conclusion that I actually arrive at in my answer is that _quoting the URL_ is the best approach. You can turn off globbing to avoid the issue with _this particular URL_, but it won't stop an URL with `&` from starting a background job.

Comment: absolutely! I wouldn't have written this as a separate answer, @Kusalananda, if I didn't have a top-level-answer-worthy thing to say on my own: the whole problem is strange, as what OP tries to do is done by default, or achievable through easier means. Matter of fact, also, my zsh simply replaces `&` in URLs with `\&` on paste – automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are probably having, which you do not actually mention, is the the `zsh` shell by default emits an error if a filename globbing pattern does not match any names:

```
$ downloadyoutube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
```

The URL here contains the character `?`, which is a globbing character.  This prompts the shell to perform filename globbing using the URL as the pattern.  No match is found, so the shell complains and does not even attempt to call your function.

A similar behavior is had in the `bash` shell if the `failglob` shell option is set:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ downloadyoutube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
bash: no match: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
```

You may stop the shell from using the URL as a globbing pattern, by setting the `NOGLOB` shell option with `setopt NOGLOB`.  This turns off globbing in the current shell session until you use `unsetopt NOGLOB`.

You may also prefix your function call with `noglob`, which has the effect of setting the `NOGLOB` shell option for a single command:

```bsh
noglob downloadyoutube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM
```

The most sane approach is however to quote the URL using single quotes in your call to your function. URLs may well contain *other* characters that are special to the shell and that are *not* globbing characters, `&` for example, which introduces a background job.  An URL with `&` in it would not be usable without quoting it, even with filename globbing turned off.

Turning off globbing also does not disable brace expansions (`{...}`) or subshells (`(...)`), which could potentially occur by accident in URLs.

Comment: Also `*` if globbing and always `! $ ; |` and backtick although the last two are not allowed unencoded in a correct URL, and I don't know if youtube uses the others